# BootStrap Continuous Slide

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is a strip down version of my website.  Using the mobile view, when the slides transitions there is a blank wipe before then next slide comes in

http://www.bootply.com/vUXtZz6HQ2

I am not quite understanding what I have to do to get the continuousswipe, that is the current slide will slide off as the next comes on the screen so it looks like it is one continuous strip,
as in the example of [Bootstrap Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)

**HTML**

```
<section class="marquee row">
  <div class="carousel slide article-slide" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover" id="mainPromotion" style="-webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); touch-action: none;">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item" data-cell-id="" data-interval="7000">
            <div class="marquee-media" data-src-md="http://placehold.it/300&amp;text=A" data-src-xs="http://placehold.it/300&amp;text=A" data-link="http://placehold.it/300&amp;text=A" data-link-target="" data-link-title="A" id="marquee0"><a href="http://placehold.it/300&amp;text=A" target="" title="A" data-tracking=""><img class="marquee-image img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300&amp;text=A"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item" data-cell-id="" data-interval="7000">
            <div class="marquee-media" data-src-md="http://placehold.it/300&amp;text=B" data-src-xs="http://placehold.it/300&amp;text=B" data-link="http://placehold.it/300&amp;text=B" data-link-target="" data-link-title="B" id="marquee1"><a href="http://placehold.it/300&amp;text=B" target="" title="B" data-tracking=""><img class="marquee-image img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300&amp;text=B"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item active" data-cell-id="" data-interval="7000">
            <div class="marquee-media" data-src-md="http://placehold.it/300&amp;text=B" data-src-xs="http://placehold.it/300&amp;text=C" data-link="http://placehold.it/300&amp;text=C" data-link-target="" data-link-title="C" id="marquee2"><a href="http://placehold.it/300&amp;text=C" target="" title="C" data-tracking=""><img class="marquee-image img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300&amp;text=C"></a></div>
          </div>
      </div>

    <ol class="carousel-indicators clearfix">
            <li class="" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#mainPromotion">
            <img alt="A" src="http://placehold.it/300&amp;text=A">
            <p class="cell-text">A</p>
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
            <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#mainPromotion" class="">
            <img alt="B" src="http://placehold.it/300&amp;text=B">
            <p class="cell-text">B</p>
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
            <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#mainPromotion" class="active">
            <img alt="C" src="http://placehold.it/300&amp;text=C">
            <p class="cell-text">C</p>
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
      </ol>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
section.marque {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

  section.marquee .cell-text {
    color: #777777;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: ProximaNova, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 125px;
  }

    section.marquee .cell-text:hover {
      background-color: #00543d;
      color: #ffffff;
    }



  section.marquee .carousel-control {
    background-image: none !important;
  }

  section.marquee .next.left,
  section.marquee .prev.right {
    -ms-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }

  section.marquee .active.left,
  section.marquee .active.right {
    -ms-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }

  section.marquee .article-slide .carousel-indicators {
    top: 0;
    left: 18px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 8px;
    width: 204px;
    z-index: 0;
  }

    section.marquee .article-slide .carousel-indicators img {
    /*float: left;
    left: 0;*/
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 70px;
    height: auto !important;
  }

  section.marquee .carousel-indicators li {
    text-indent: 0 !important;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    display: inline-block;
    -ms-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: -2px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto !important;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
  }

    section.marquee .carousel-indicators li i {
      display: none;
    }

    section.marquee .carousel-indicators li:hover .cell-text {
      background-color: #00543d;
      color: #ffffff;
    }

    section.marquee .carousel-indicators li.active .cell-text {
      color: #00543d;
    }

    section.marquee .carousel-indicators li.active:hover .cell-text {
      color: #ffffff;
    }

    section.marquee .carousel-indicators li.active {
      border: 3px solid #00543d;
      color: #00543d;
      margin-left: -1px;
      margin-bottom: -1px;
    }

      section.marquee .carousel-indicators li.active i {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        text-indent: 0 !important;
        right: -12px;
        top: 15px;
      }

section.marquee .edit-marquee-cell {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 45%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    section.marquee .item img,
    section.marquee .carousel {
       width: 768px;
       height: 300px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    section.marquee .item img,
    section.marquee .carousel {
      width: 100% !important;
      height: auto !important;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 991px) {
  /* fade effect */
  section.marquee .carousel .item {
    z-index: 0;
    left: 0 !important;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .4s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .4s;
    -o-transition: opacity .4s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .4s;
    transition: opacity .4s;
  }
}


@media(max-width : 991px) {
  section.marquee .carousel-indicators li.active i,
  section.marquee .carousel-indicators img,
  section.marquee .carousel-indicators .cell-text {
    display: none !important;
  }

  section.marquee .carousel-indicators {
    position: relative !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    width: 80px !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    left: auto !important;
    right: auto !important;
    top: auto !important;
    bottom: 0;
  }


    section.marquee .carousel-indicators li {
      display: inline-block !important;
      width: 15px !important;
      height: 15px !important;
      margin: 1px !important;
      border: 1px solid #bcbcbc !important;
      -ms-border-radius: 10px !important;
      border-radius: 10px !important;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

        section.marquee .carousel-indicators li.active {
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px !important;
            background-color: #00543d !important;
        }



            backface-visibility: hidden;
            perspective: 1000;
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -webkit-perspective: 1000;
      }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
  var validFlag = false;



  $(window).on({
    "load": function() {
      if (!window.marqueeJson) return;

      var imageTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("#template-marquee-images").html());
      var fragTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("#template-marquee-frags").html());

      var compiledInner = $("section.marquee .carousel-inner");
      var compiledFrags = $("section.marquee .carousel-indicators");

      compiledInner.html(imageTemplate(window.marqueeJson));
      compiledFrags.html(fragTemplate(window.marqueeJson));

      if (window.marqueeJson.Cells.length == 1) {
        compiledFrags.remove();
        $("section.marquee .carousel-control").remove();
      }

      if (compiledInner.length > 0) {
        validFlag = true;

        var mainPromo = document.getElementById("mainPromotion");
        var mc = new window.Hammer(mainPromo);

        mc.on("swipeleft", function () {
            $(mainPromo).carousel("next");
        });
        mc.on("swiperight", function () {
            $(mainPromo).carousel("prev");
        });

        updateMarquee();

        var carouselStartPromo = function (promoPos) {
            if (!isNaN(promoPos) && (0 < promoPos) && (promoPos < 3)) {
                $('#mainPromotion').carousel(promoPos);
            } else {
                $('#mainPromotion').carousel();
            }
        };

        var t;
        var promoStart = -1;
        carouselStartPromo(promoStart);

        $('#mainPromotion').carousel('pause');
        var start = $('#mainPromotion').find('.active').attr('data-interval');

        t = setTimeout(carouselStartPromo, start - 7000);

          /* 
          This event is to fix an IE bug where the swf file does not replay when the marquee control cycles
          around. It looks ahead to the next item before the slide event happens (or to the first item, if there 
          isn't an item after the active one) and reloads the swf by re-embedding it. This only fires if the 
          useragent contains "MSIE" for Internet Explorer.
          */
        $('#mainPromotion').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
            if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') > -1){
                var params = { menu: "false", wmode: "transparent" };
                var self;

                if ($('#mainPromotion').find('.active + .item').length > 0) {
                    self = $('#mainPromotion').find('.active + .item').find('.marquee-media');
                }
                else {
                    self = $('#mainPromotion').find('.item').first().find('.marquee-media');
                }

                var flashMedia = self.attr("data-src-flv") !== undefined ? self.attr("data-src-flv") : false;

                if (flashMedia) {
                    var flashId = self.attr("id") + "-flash";
                    swfobject.embedSWF(flashMedia, flashId, "100%", "300", "9.0", false, false, params);
                }
            }
        });

        $('#mainPromotion').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
            clearTimeout(t);
            var duration = $('#mainPromotion').find('.active').attr('data-interval');

            $('#mainPromotion').carousel('pause');
            t = setTimeout(carouselStartPromo, duration - 7000);
        });

        /* Marquee Unit Tracking (cells tracking in handlebar helpers) */
        if (window.marqueeJson.AnalyticId.length > 1) {
          $("#mainPromotion").attr("data-tracking", window.marqueeJson.AnalyticId);
        }
      }


    },
    "resize": function() {
      if (!validFlag) return;

      waitForFinalEvent(function() {
        updateMarquee();
      }, 300, new Date().getTime());
    }
  });

  function updateMarquee() {


});
```

Comment: can you post it in jsfiddle..bootply site blocked here..

Comment: Can someone describe why they are choosing to close the question?

Comment: Please edit your question, and clarify what you mean by "continuous swipe". Please also provide a minimal example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @Ben so I added the definition of continuous swipe as for a minimal example, I provided the bootply with just the carousel tag.  I provided the code, which I don't like to do but +shri objected because bootply is blocked from their country.  I have to admit I am confused as to why this question is unclear since +user3365721 answered the question so beautifully

Comment: Thank you all for not following up.

Comment: Yea... Popular question badge... maybe it should have never been closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through your code the problem is caused in the css with these styles

```
  section.marquee .next.left,
  section.marquee .prev.right {
    -ms-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }

  section.marquee .active.left,
  section.marquee .active.right {
    -ms-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
```

Removing these will get it working. What is happening is that the `opacity:0;` is applying straight away and so you just get a blank square.

If what your looking to do is have a fade out fade in effect on the slides, I think `transition : opacity 1s ease;` might help.

---

see below image of class being applied.

[image: next class being applied]

Comment: So removing this worked, and it does not seem to impact the desktop version.  Thank you   Where I am confused is if I look at the code I don't see the classes next, prev, right, left.  Even using Google tools all I see is the active class being rotated.  Where/when was this style being applied.

Comment: fyi it says I have to wait another 12 hours to award bounty

Comment: Those classes are only applied when you press the next or previous buttons or use the indicators to jump around. If you open the bootply to one side of the screen and have the google tools visible on the other when you change image you can see the classes applied then removed.

Comment: added an image to the answer of the next class being applied

Comment: Yes I see it now, it very quickly gets added and removed.

Answer (score 0):

line 40,

```
if (!isNaN(promoPos) && (0 < promoPos) && (promoPos < 3)) {
            $('#mainPromotion').carousel(promoPos);
```

update 4 by 3.

Comment: Yes that was a mistake because my original site had four slides, changing to 3 does not change the behavior.